# javascript max call stack exceeded explanation

Tags: javascript, recursion, multidimensional-array

```
var MultiArray = (function(){

    var MultiArray = function(param){

            var i = param.array.length;
            while(i--){
                param.array[i] = MultiArray({
                array: new Array(dims[0]),
                dims: dims.splice(1,dims.length-1)
                });
            }

        return param.array

    };

    return function(){

        var length = arguments.length - 1;
            array = new Array(arguments[0]),
            dims = [length];

        for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
            dims[i] = arguments[i+1];
        }   

        MultiArray({
            array: array,
            dims: dims
        });

        return array;
    };

})();
```

I'm trying to write a function that will create multidimensional arrays so `var mdArray = MultiArray(3,3,3);` would create a 3D array of 3x3x3 elements. But I get Max call stack size exceeded when trying this method, is there a better way of making a multidimensional array function like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var MultiArray = (function() {

    var MultiArray = function(param) {

        var myDims, i = param.array.length;
        if(param.dims.length === 0){
            return;
        }
        while(i--) {
            myDims = param.dims.slice(0);
            myDims = myDims.splice(1, myDims.length - 1);
            param.array[i] = new Array(param.dims[0]);
            MultiArray({
                array : param.array[i],
                dims : myDims
            });
        }

    };

    return function() {

        var length = arguments.length - 1, array = new Array(arguments[0]), dims = [length];

        for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            dims[i] = arguments[i + 1];
        }

        MultiArray({
            array : array,
            dims : dims
        });

        return array;
    };
})();
```

The code above is correct the original code was simply wrong causing an infinite recursive loop, now it works as intended, `var mdArray = MultiArray(2,3,4,5);` creates an array with dimensions 2x3x4x5. The recursive function now returns straight away when the `dims` array in the argument has zero length.

Answer (score 0):

In your inner `MultiArray`, you always have a `param.array` with 1 items, which makes a endless recursion.